# Using primeng form controls and angular reactive forms how can I get the value of the dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a primeng dropdown component....

```
 <form [formGroup]="skillsForm">
      <p-dropdown [options]="experienceList" optionLabel="name" formControlName="example" ></p-dropdown>
</form>
```

Deep inside of nested form groups and arrays, so I need to use reactive forms.

I attempt to get the pickers value using

```
skillsForm.value.example
```

and get the item

```
{name: 'Over a year', value: '1.0'}
```

selected in that field back.

This is good, however, I want the value 1.0 for that specified field. Thus I'd expect primeng to have an option to allow you to specify the value returned, but I can't identify that.

Comment: Not enough detail, give us the code for all the relevant parts

Comment: Hey Mike, I'll add a full Plunker later if still no responses, however this is 90% of the code.

Comment: This seems to be a common issue: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=61302
Question was asked there, but as usual with prime, no response.

Answer (score 0):

declare a variable in your componenet say "selectedElement "and bind it to your 
dropdown as shown below:

The select value will be bind to your selectedElement

Comment: Thanks for the response, but your answer is suggesting normal binding. This needs to be done with form controls as mentioned, This is because it's got as many combos as the user adds & so can't be resolved this way.

Comment: import {SelectItem} from 'primeng/primeng';



experienceList : SelectItem[];

 experienceList= [
            {label:'Select Skill', value:null},
            {label:'Over a year', value:1.0}
           
        ];


example.value;